# Firebase remote config requires app restart twice to refresh?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

I've implemented Firebase Remote Config into my Android app, so I can update the information shown in the app as needed. If I update the parameters in the Firebase console, and then and open the app on my device, it still shows the previous values. I have to close the app, then reopen it again to see the updated values. Due to the nature of the information being displayed to the user, I need it to be up-to-date right away. Is there any way to have it show the current values without requiring the app to be reopened again? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Here's the code I'm using for this:

```
val remoteConfig = Firebase.remoteConfig
val configSettings = remoteConfigSettings {
    minimumFetchIntervalInSeconds = 0
}
remoteConfig.setConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings)
remoteConfig.setDefaultsAsync(R.xml.remote_config_defaults)
remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()

val valueOne = remoteConfig.getString("valueOne")
```

Comment: A brief restart is required to fetch new values. If you want to update the UI right away then you should use a combination of RemoteConfig & FCM.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you need to restart the value is because Remote Config is not listening or monitoring to the server value while the app is running. It only gets the value while the app restarts or reaches a specific period of time.

A workaround is to enable Firestore for your app and let your app listens to the Firestore in realtime, so once you updated your template, you can also update the version / flag in Firestore manually or through a triggered cloud function, then you can explicitly fetch the new template in your app.

By the way, if your app requires you restart twice to display the updated value, maybe you also needs to consider using React Native or similar frameworks to let the UI be able refresh immediately while a variable has been updated.